# How to get POSIX group name from gid in Java

Tags: java, posix

In Java on a Linux host, I need to be able to set the POSIX group of arbitrary files to the group specified by a passed in gid.

I'm aware that to modify a group in Java, I can do this:

```
UserPrincipalLookupService lookupService = FileSystems.getDefault().getUserPrincipalLookupService();
GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = lookupService.lookupPrincipalByGroupName(groupName);
Files.getFileAttributeView(myFile.toPath(), PosixFileAttributeView.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS).setGroup(group);
```

However, this is based on knowing the group name, when I only know the gid. Is there anyway to either get the group name for a given group id in Java, or directly set the group of a file in Java given a gid? Since the user running the process is guaranteed to be a member of the gid specified, if I could obtain a Map of every gid -> groupName pair that the user is a member of, that would work.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica The OP wants a group name, not a user id.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The OP says "or directly set the group of a file in Java given a gid", and the dupe target explains that you can do that with `"unix:gid"`, like this: `Files.setAttribute(myFile.toPath(), "unix:gid", gid);`.

Comment: The question you link to, never actually mentions Files.setAttribute, but thank you, knowing that exists answers my question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel why reopen this?

Comment: (for anyone else reading this: it was previously voted closed as a duplicate of [How to get numeric groupid/userid using java7 file attribute apis?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6446508/7509065))

Comment: Because this is not the same question. The OP is asking for the group name, not the user id, and your argument that _the OP says "or directly set the group of a file in Java given a gid"_ is not correct, because that is also not answered by that question.